# iPhone app Development Target change in xocde4.2.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I have submit my app in app store successfully and got approve from apple but the app Development Targer is 5.0 and developed in Xcode 4.2.1(mac os x). So its not installed in IOS 4 devices from app store, now how can i solve this problem and get run on all (i.e) from IOS 3 devices.

Comment: keep the base sdk to maximum ie 5.0 and deployment target to minimum.. ie from 3 onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the deployment target to whatever **minimum** iOS version you want to target. You can set this in your Project's Target, as in the screenshot below:

[image]

However, it's a good idea to keep the Base SDK at the latest released version; which is currently 5.1:

[image]

Note, in order for people to now be able to download your app on the new minimum version, you will need to reupload a **new** binary to the App Store for review and acceptance.

Comment: hi thanks but now i try to build after above change but it shows the following error i.e "The current deployment target does not support automated_weak references" on @sythesize statement. Then new binary submit means, is it add new version?     By madhubalan.

Comment: Correct. Weak is only valid on iOS 5+. You will need to replace all weak attributes with assign. The difference is that weak attributes automatically set the property to nil, whereas with assign you will need to do this manually.

Comment: thanks jmstone now got the warning: iPhone apps with a deployment target lower than 4.3 should include an armv6 architecture (current IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = "3.0", ARCHS = "armv7") like  where should i add the armv6. i have changed from armv7 to armv6 in info.plist's "required devices capabilities" but no use. thanks

Comment: i am sorry i am new to here i don't know how to accept this answer.

Comment: There is a little blank check mark to the left of the answer, under the up/down arrows. Click it.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not wrong you need to rebuild you application and then resubmit it to apple again .

as i know there is no other way to change the target devices..

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try this U can surely  get out this error

In your project -> build settings -> architectures, try adding an arm6 architecture

in architectures add both armv6 and armv7