# Line break in UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, newline

I have this code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 275, 40)];
label.text = @"I am learning Objective-C for the\n very first time!";
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

But for some reason it doesn't insert a new line... how do I put a line break in an `UILabel`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please check that

```
   UILabel *yourLabel;
   yourLabel.numberoflines = 0
```

or not..

if it is not like this please set it to zero

Comment: once set it to zero and check

Comment: @muqman : if u hvnt declare UILabel variable (that means u added it directly on nib) , so u can check number of line property on right side panel of nib in which u added UILabel. No need to declare it, u can change it from nib too.

Comment: Yes...we can do it from nib file also.

Comment: @NSS true but I am actually simply trying to understand how to program in Objective-C without the tools so I can go ahead and make something...

Comment: is it possible to add word wrap?

Comment: now i am trying @"I am learning Objective-C for the\nvery first time! Also, this is my\nfirst ever variable"; but it isnt working for the last \n

Comment: @muqman Please see the docs for UILabel. You will find methods for the  number of lines and wrapping (as well as plenty of others). Make the reference docs your best friend.

Comment: lable.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

Comment: @rmaddy maybe so but its not as easy to understand as SO :)

Comment: SO if great for asking specific questions but you'll never get far if you don't learn how to scan the reference docs for the available classes, methods, and properties. You should only ask a question when you can't find the answer in the docs. Enjoy the learning.

Answer (score 3):

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 275, 40)];
label.text = @"I am learning Objective-C for the\n very first time!";
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0;

[self.view addSubview:label];`
```

Comment: this is depricated in iOS 6... what do i do about that...?

Comment: if you use ios6 only change the UILineBreakModeWordWrap  to NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Comment: yes if your project targeted to ios 5 or above use UILineBreakModeWordWrap  it will work on both ios5/6  but if your project is only targeted to ios6 then you will get a deprecation message on it or you have to use the NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Comment: how do i change the target?

Comment: this question might help you in this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414712/iphone-app-development-target-change-in-xocde4-2-1

Comment: thanks! One more question, how do I make 2 pages so I can display different text on each. Will be done on ViewController.m or will it be another page? How will I implement this, I think I made a sing view application so I can learn the programming behind all of this.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all sorts of different solutions to get a newline in my UILabel.

\r will do the trick!  For example:

```
NSString *detailInfo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Address:\r%@", self.aAddress.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution compared to @JanB's one, you can insert an `NSString` object: `@"\n"` into the formatting string:

In your example:

`label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I am learning Objective-C for the%@ very first time!", @"\n"];`

Let me know if there is a problem :)